# Cannot loop over an array

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I'm trying to insert the following worklog JSON fields that are part of an array using Python however I don't seem to be able to loop over an array in Python.

See code snippet below:

```
try:
    worklogs_to_insert = []
    for i in issue.fields.worklog["worklogs"]:
        worklogs_to_insert.append(i)
except AttributeError as e:
    log.info("Something went wrong when processing worklogs. :(")
    log.info(e)
```

---

I am getting the following error when script is run:

```
Something went wrong when processing worklogs. :(
type object 'PropertyHolder' has no attribute 'worklog'
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: What is confusing you about this error? `issue.fields` is apparently the PropertyHolder class, which does not have a attribute called "worklog".

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
for i in issue.fields.worklog.raw["worklogs"]
```

Comment: thanks still not getting the same error

Comment: i cannot install jirashell or jiraclient as i do not have the console privileges. Any other suggestions?